# Separate NFS harddrive mounted to an ISCSI stored VMware virtual machine

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter, vmware-server

Is it possible to add an NFS storage harddrive to an already existing VM that is stored on an ISCSI storage repository?

I'm specifically trying to mount an NFS repository to this VM for backup purposes within the OS.

Comment: From what I understood, you have tried to add another .vmdk that is stored on NFS datastore. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes.  Sorry I just hadn't set it up on both my hosts in that location, so it wasn't created on the right host yet.  Set the NFS up on the host where the VM resided and it showed up, GO FIGURE!